# Auto connect bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-broadcastreceiver

I am newbie to android, I am trying to connect my phone to a known bluetooth device (i.e,MAC address is hard coded). When I try to connect it for the 1st time, that is working fine with broadcast receiver concept

```
 IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
 registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, discoverDevicesIntent);
```

My requirement now is when the Bluetooth device is turned off and again turned on, my app is not not connecting to the device automatically. How to achieve this ? Should I use service concept ? Or is there any easy method to achieve this ? Please help me.